# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Is it ok to create & link 100 shader programs at once on a typical Android device?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I'd like to try to create and link up to 100 shader programs (probably 40) at once via `glCreateProgram` and `glLinkProgram` (and switch between them in `onDrawFrame` if I need to).

Each one woud have simple uniforms like one or 2 vec4s, or a single float, etc. Simple question: what is the approximate limit on a typical Android device on the number of such shader programs I can create and link at once? Would 40-100 be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLES2 docs don't mention any specific limit to how many programs you can keep in memory. I guess you could compile and link 10.000's of programs. The only limit should be the amount of memory available. It all depends on the program, both the ascii-source and the compiled binary will be stored by the GLES context.

For other limits, look what the glGet* functions can return.

[glGet[Booleanv|Floatv|Integerv], gles2 docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml)